# Update value only if changed in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with 80000-90000 records having an id field and a relevance score field. 
There is one python program that calculates relevance score for each id. I want to update the records in database only if the relevance score calculated by the python program is different from the score present in the database.
The database I'm using is postgres.

For example -
Initial Database state is
Id   -  relevance_score
1   -  23
2    -  12
3    -  14
Lets say the new relevance score calculated for id=2 is 15 by the python program and Scores of id=1 and id=3 are calculated as 23 and 14(same as before)
I want to write update query only for id=2 so the new database state would be
Id  -  relevance_score
1    -  23
2      - 15
3    -   14

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Can you explain in more detail? What problems do you encounter updating a table only if a value has changed? How does your `UPDATE` statement look so far?

Comment: The table already has relevance scores for each id. In some other program I'm calculating relevance scores for each id. I want to update the score in database only if the new score calculated is different from the score in the database.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the table is called `scores` and the fields `id` and `relevance`, you can update a single row like that:

```
UPDATE scores
SET relevance = <new value>
WHERE id = 42
  AND relevance <> <new value>;
```

That will update the row only if the value has changed.